# .htaccess - php_value with url match

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

Apache doesn't let `.htaccess` use frills such as `Location`, `Directory` - without these, is it possible to match a url pattern and set php configuration settings (via `php_value`) in a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, use Files and FilesMatch in a htaccess file.

Comment: The problem is you can't match a URL pattern - so if something is handled through a single index.php / front controller it will have unwanted effects.

Comment: He didn't show a URL *pattern* - he showed a filename, file.php.

Comment: Apologies - I was just trying to fill in my question a bit; it looks bare without some form of example. I didn't intend on contradicting my question.

Answer (score 0):

Location and Directory don't make as much sense for .htaccess files because you can just put them in the directory that it matches to.

Comment: Unless a directory doesn't exist and everything is routed through a front controller